# High level system design meal suggestion

Tags: architecture, system, system-design

I was asked the following question:

> Please design an application where the user can:
>
> - Add his favorite ingredients
> - Ask for a meal with those ingredients that he have added

I am trying to figure out how should I approach such a system design question.
Should I first ask the interviewer how much load do we expect and upon that choose a DB?
In case you chose SQL, what are the advantages and disadvantages in this case? How would NOSQL database could make the solution better?